# How to update value before Property Transfer

Tags: soapui

I'm new in SOAPUI and I have a problem trying to change the extracted value before write it down to Custom Property.
I have Response:

```
"<Response xmlns="https://company.com/webapi/Login">
     <token>ABCDEF</token>
</Response>"
```

I extracted value from "ABCDEF" using Property Transfer:

```
"declare namespace var="https://company.com/webapi/Login";
//var:Response/var:token"
```

and saved it as Custom Property.
But I need to save it as "*-_*ABCDEF"

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath function concat to do this.

Learn more about Xpath here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

```
declare namespace var="https://company.com/webapi/Login";
concat("*-_*",//var:Response/var:token)
```

Comment: W3Schools are discouraged, as many of their tutorials are incorrect. For learning XPath, try this: http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html